# jQuery Select List Id as Parameter in Function and Get Selected Value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to pass Select List Id as parameter in Function and check if it has value.
If it doesn't have value, I want to get label text above this element and display error message, but I constantly get error: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object] option:selected, or if I remove option:selected I get undefined.

Can you please help me with this function?

Here is my code:

```
function ValidateDropDownListEmpty(dropDownListId) {

    var elementId = $("#" + dropDownListId);
    var elementValue = $(elementId + " option:selected").val();

    var closestLabelText = $(elementId).parent().closest("label.dropdownLabel").text();

    if (!elementValue) {
        swal({
            title: "Error!!!",
            text: "Make Choice " + closestLabelText + "!!!",
            
            showCancelButton: false,
            showConfirmButton: true,
            confirmButtonText: 'Ok',
            dangerMode: true
        }).then(function () {
            $(elementId).focus();
        });
        
        return false;
    };

    return true;
};
```

Comment: `elementId` is, as the error already shows, an object (a jQuery object). Why do you pass the id selector string to jQuery when you only want the selector? `$("#" + dropDownListId);` -> `"#" + dropDownListId;`

Answer (score 1):

Better using vanilla JavaScript and reduce the jQuery usage.

```
document.querySelector('#my-select option:checked').value;
```

but if you want the jQuery way example to your code:
it will be either this:

```
var elementValue = $(`#${dropDownListId} option:checked`).val();
```

or this:

```
var elementValue = $('#' + dropDownListId + ' option:checked').val();
```

Comment: Or ``var elementValue = $(`#${downloadListId}`).val();`` if the `select` is not `multiple`.

Comment: according to my understand from his example, it is a single value select.

Comment: As in your answer and also as Andreas said in the comment above I was assigning object to element id var instead of selector, but I was already frustrated and wasn't thinking anymore. Thank You all.  This is the line I changed: var elementId = `#${dropDownListId}`;

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of the currently selected option in a select, try this:

```js
const selectEl = document.getElementById('my-select');
const selectValue = selectEl.options[selectEl.selectedIndex].value;
console.log(selectValue);
```

Comment: Why vanilla JS when OP just has to correctly use the id selector with the given jQuery setup?

Comment: Didn't really think about that, but this is 2022 and there is no reason to use jQuery for something like this!  